# How can I access cookies from a model in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cookies, model

I am using the Koala gem to interact with the Facebook API.  In order to connect to the API, I need to pass my cookies to Koala.  I want to do this in a model because I want to add additional data to the user from Facebook data during a before_create callback in the model.  For instance, if a user has an active FB session, store their Facebook UID when creating their user row.  How do I get at cookies from within a model?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Models should not be aware they're operating in a web environment.

What you might want to consider instead is just storing the FB UID on the model the same way as any other property, by setting it on the model during creation.

Comment: Why? To my understanding, models are a wrapper around the storage of the data in the MVC pattern. If the data is stored in the cookie, why shouldn't the model be aware of the web environment? If the goal is separation of data storage from data viewing and data processing, there's nothing wrong with it. So, I am interested in hearing your reason why.

Comment: @Rokujolady The OP is asking a question (how do I get a cookie from the model) when what they *need* is a *value* from a cookie. *Values* aren't tied to the web, cookies are. The "goal" is separation of *unrelated layers*, and the data has no reason to know about the web, it simply needs a *value* from the web. By separating them you can get the data from *anywhere*, like a test, or a service, or etc.

Comment: Fair enough. From your response and from other research I'm starting to see that this is more of a rails-centric interpretation of MVC than inherent in the pattern. In short, I think the real answer is "do it because rails framework is set up to handle it this way and will make your life miserable if you don't toe the line!" It's not against MVC in general because the thing manipulating the data, the controller, shouldn't care where the data is stored...on the cookie on the drive of the client or in a server db.

Comment: @rokujolady This has nothing to do with Rails. This has to do with keeping two completely disparate chunks of functionality separated. The model needs to know the Facebook id, period. There is no other connection other than the id. It's nonsensical to tie the model to *cookies*, a purely web artifact, to get this id. Something that responds to a facebook_id method, or a hash with a reasonable key, sure- neither of which require accessing web-layer artifacts from a non-web-layer artifact.

Comment: I agree. In this case it makes sense to use the session cookie field as a parameter to the controller to look up an item in the db. I'm just saying that there are cases where a model could reasonably wrap a cookie and its not always bad design.

Comment: @rokujolady Show me the example; I can't think of any reason not to airways separate the data from the web.