# Is it bad practice to include URL helpers in Rails models?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Project Model Exemple

```
 class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    include ActionView::Helpers
    include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

Comment: it depend upon your requirement, i would suggest you to add it in module instead of model if you need badly in model then you can go for it.

Answer (score 4):

IMO yes, this is bad. Models shouldn't need to be concerned about the view layer.

I've never had a need for this, either; I'm having a hard time coming up with a use case.

AFAIC this is similar to wanting to [access cookies from a model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884630/how-can-i-access-cookies-from-a-model-in-rails-3/7884660#7884660), which I also think is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Sometimes you have no choice, so you might have to resort to that. Nevertheless, we can only give a proper answer if you have a use case.